# Create-react-app breaks when i delete index.css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

why does my create-react-app break when I delete the index.css file during cleaning the app

Comment: Hi, what is the error? probably it breaks because it is used in some files .

Comment: To further Oscars point, you're likely still trying to import the `index.css` file in your `index.js` file. But I agree, an error message would be useful.

Comment: I think create-react-app is using webpack in the background. Webpack is set up to use index.css so when you remove it, it breaks. Why are you deleting it?

Comment: @Craicerjack thank you answered me very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your index.js file where its import index.css, so remove the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import in the index.js, you'll be good to go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).